# TYPO3 Multidomain Website Preview shows only Default Language

Tags: typo3, preview, multilingual, multiple-domains, realurl

I'm using `TYPO3 7.6` with a multidomain and multilanguage Website, you see the links below. I've one page tree and `rootpage_id` for all three languages!

1. First language is german (L=0, https://www.renosan.de/)
2. Second language is english (L=1, https://www.renosan.net/)
3. Third language is polish (L=2, https://www.renosan.pl/)

For every language I'm using an own top-level domain (de,net,pl). I've also insert the domain records at my root page (TYPO3-Backend List -> Rootpage -> Domain records)

If I'm clicking at the preview button (s. image), the preview opens in a new window with: [image: typo3 backend preview page]

- English: https://www.renosan.de/index.php?id=1&L=1
- Polish: https://www.renosan.de/index.php?id=1&L=2

... but the content is still in the default language (german)! I need to change the `TLD` to change the Website language manually. It's not useful for my editors, because they aren't seeing the preview with one click.

Can someone explain the behaviour from `TYPO3`?

I also tried to login into Backend from `.net` or `.pl`, nothing happens. It's always the default preview. No special `.htaccess` entries ...

My TypoScript Setup

```
### default german
config {
  linkVars = L(0-2)
  uniqueLinkVars = 1

  sys_language_mode = content_fallback
  sys_language_overlay = hideNonTranslated
  sys_language_uid = 0

  language = de
  locale_all = de_DE.UTF8
  htmlTag_langKey = de
}


### english L=1
[globalString = IENV:HTTP_HOST = *renosan.net]
config {
    baseURL = https://www.renosan.net/
    sys_language_uid = 1
    language = en
    locale_all = en_GB.UTF8
    htmlTag_langKey = en
}
[GLOBAL]


### polski L=2
[globalString = IENV:HTTP_HOST = *renosan.pl]
config {
    baseURL = https://www.renosan.pl/
    sys_language_uid = 2
    language = pl
    locale_all = pl_PL.UTF8
    htmlTag_langKey = pl
}
[GLOBAL]
```

I have locate the problem with my individual `realURL-conf`. If I try it with the 'autoconf' from `Ext:realURL`the preview from Backend works!

Here's my personal realURL-Configuration file:

```
<?php
$TYPO3_CONF_VARS['EXTCONF']['realurl']['_DEFAULT'] = array(
    'pagePath' => array(
        'type' => 'user',
        'userFunc' => 'EXT:realurl/class.tx_realurl_advanced.php:&tx_realurl_advanced->main',
        'spaceCharacter' => '-',
        'languageGetVar' => 'L',
        'expireDays' => '3',
        'rootpage_id' => 1,
        'firstHitPathCache'=> 1
    ),
    'init' => array(
        'enableCHashCache' => 1,
        'respectSimulateStaticURLs' => 0,
        'postVarSet_failureMode' => '',
        'enableUrlDecodeCache' => 1,
        'enableUrlEncodeCache' => 1
    ),
    'preVars' => array(
        array(
            'GETvar' => 'L',
            'valueMap' => array(
                //'de' => '0',
                'en' => '1',
                'pl' => '2'
            ),
            'noMatch' => 'bypass',
        ),
        array(
            'GETvar' => 'no_cache',
            'valueMap' => array(
                'nc' => 1,
            ),
            'noMatch' => 'bypass',
        ),
    ),

    'fixedPostVars' => array(
        'newsDetailConfiguration' => array(
            array(
                'GETvar' => 'tx_news_pi1[action]',
                'valueMap' => array(
                    'detail' => '',
                ),
                'noMatch' => 'bypass',
            ),
            array(
                'GETvar' => 'tx_news_pi1[controller]',
                'valueMap' => array(
                    'News' => '',
                ),
                'noMatch' => 'bypass',
            ),

            array(
                'GETvar' => 'tx_news_pi1[news]',
                'lookUpTable' => array(
                    'table' => 'tx_news_domain_model_news',
                    'id_field' => 'uid',
                    'alias_field' => 'title',
                    'addWhereClause' => ' AND NOT deleted',
                    'useUniqueCache' => 1,
                    'useUniqueCache_conf' => array(
                        'strtolower' => 1,
                        'spaceCharacter' => '-',
                    ),
                    'languageGetVar' => 'L',
                    'languageExceptionUids' => '',
                    'languageField' => 'sys_language_uid',
                    'transOrigPointerField' => 'l10n_parent',
                    'autoUpdate' => 1,
                    'expireDays' => 180,
                ),
            ),
        ),

        '42' => 'newsDetailConfiguration',
        '43' => 'newsDetailConfiguration',
    ),
    'postVarSets' => array(
        '_DEFAULT' => array(
            'controller' => array(
                array(
                    'GETvar' => 'tx_news_pi1[action]',
                    'noMatch' => 'bypass',
                ),
                array(
                    'GETvar' => 'tx_news_pi1[controller]',
                    'noMatch' => 'bypass',
                ),
            ),
            'tags' => array(
                array(
                    'GETvar' => 'tx_news_pi1[overwriteDemand][tags]',
                    'lookUpTable' => array (
                        'table' => 'tx_news_domain_model_tag',
                        'id_field' => 'uid',
                        'alias_field' => 'title',
                        'addWhereClause' => 'AND NOT deleted',
                        'useUniqueCache' => 1,
                        'useUniqueCache_conf' => array (
                            'strtolower' => 1,
                            'spaceCharacter' => '-',
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            ),

            'seite' => array(
                array(
                    'GETvar' => 'tx_news_pi1[@widget_0][currentPage]',
                ),
            ),

            // news archive parameters
            'archiv' => array(
                array(
                    'GETvar' => 'tx_news_pi1[overwriteDemand][year]',
                ),
                array(
                    'GETvar' => 'tx_news_pi1[overwriteDemand][month]',
                    'valueMap' => array(
                        'january' => '01',
                        'february' => '02',
                        'march' => '03',
                        'april' => '04',
                        'may' => '05',
                        'june' => '06',
                        'july' => '07',
                        'august' => '08',
                        'september' => '09',
                        'october' => '10',
                        'november' => '11',
                        'december' => '12',
                    ),
                ),
            ),

        ),
    ),
);



$TYPO3_CONF_VARS['EXTCONF']['realurl']['_DOMAINS'] = array(
    'encode' => array(
        array(
            'GETvar' => 'L',
            'value' => '0',
            'useConfiguration' => 'renosan.de',
            'urlPrepend' => 'https://www.renosan.de'
        ),
        array(
            'GETvar' => 'L',
            'value' => '1',
            'useConfiguration' => 'renosan.de',
            'urlPrepend' => 'https://www.renosan.net'
        ),
        [
            'GETvar' => 'L',
            'value' => '2',
            'useConfiguration' => 'renosan.de',
            'urlPrepend' => 'https://www.renosan.pl'
        ],

    ),
    'decode' => array(
        'renosan.de' => array(
            'GETvars' => array(
                'L' => '0',
            ),
            'useConfiguration' => 'renosan.de'
        ),
        'renosan.net' => array(
            'GETvars' => array(
                'L' => '1',
            ),
            'useConfiguration' => 'renosan.de'
        ),
        'renosan.pl' => array(
            'GETvars' => array(
                'L' => '2',
            ),
            'useConfiguration' => 'renosan.de'
        ),
    )
);
?>
```

Thanks for your help .. **I have still no solution for this TYPO3-Problem?! Is it a TYPO3-Bug? Is there a problem with my realURL-Configuration-File?**

Answer (score 0):

I think your conditions are wrong and TYPO3 gets so confused that the conditions are ignored completely.

it is not

```
[global string = ENV: HTTP_HOST = ...
```

but:

```
[globalString = ENV:HTTP_HOST = ...
```

On the other hand I assume your TYPO3 will also gets confused about domains and additional language parameter. For preview you need to be logged in into the BE (cookies are domain dependend). So a preview in another language is possible only  with language parameter. Your configuration mixes domains and language parameter: if you start with `www.renosan.de?L=1` your baseurl is changed.
My recommandation: Split the handling depending on domain and L-Param.

Comment: First, thanks for your answer. I will check my conditions. I also logged in with different domains, like `.net` or `.pl` to test it, because of the cookie. Nothing happens, What do you mean with "split". I will need the L-Parameter to manage the languages, didn't I?

Comment: In general try to avoid `baseurl` at all. if you need to use baseurl, then don't set the baseurl if working with L-parameter. => separate conditions on domain, which set the according baseurl.

Comment: Hi Bernd, now I avoid baseURL at all. I use `absRefPrefix = auto` now (https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/Setup/Config/Index.html?highlight=absrefprefix#absrefprefix). There's no `baseURL` in my source code.  My conditions are still `[globalString = ENV:HTTP_HOST = https://www.renosan.net/] ... sys_language_uid = 1 ...` f.e.

Comment: Hi Bernd. Now I use realURL with autoconf and the preview from backend works. I have some mistakes in my own realURLconf ... It works with the L-Parameter

Answer (score 0):

If you use RealURL: Look at [this blog post](http://www.dmitry-dulepov.com/2009/02/realurl-separate-language-domains-in.html). Here you can see how to config realURL to watch at the Domains to seperate languages.

After that, you dont need conditions about the domains. You can use the simple `[globalVar = GP:L = x]` conditions.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your reply. I use realURL autoconf and now the preview will shown (with the L-Parameter). So there must be sth. wrong with my realUrlConf-file?!?

Comment: The auto configuration don't see the domain language Config. So you must manually configure realurl.

Comment: Maybe you own configuration missed the language var

Comment: No, I already have it. `preVars ... GETvar => 'L' ... 'de' => '0', 'en' => '1', ...` I will test it with my own realurl conf. Maybe I have changed to much .. so I will make a clean restart for my configuration.